# Optimize deletion of multiple objects that depend on a parent object

Tags: c#, performance, linq, optimization

I am trying to develop an API in C# where I perform CRUD operations on students and their grades. Each student has multiple grades and when a student is deleted, his/her grades are deleted as well.
I created multiple functions:

this one deletes a student:

```
public async Task<long> DeleteStudentAsync(long id)
{
    Student student = await _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Student>().GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);
    
    await DeleteStudentGrade(student.Grades);
    
    student.IsDeleted = true;
    
    await _unitofwork.SaveChangesAsync();

    return studentId;
}
```

this one is a helper/intermediate:

```
private async Task DeleteStudentGrade(IEnumerable<Grade> grades)
{
    foreach(Grade grade in grades)
    {
        if(grade.isDeleted)
        {
            continue;
        }
        
        await DeleteGradeAsync(grade.IdStudent, grade.id);
    }
}
```

this one deletes the grades and also, importantly, logs the grades deleted with addToHistoryGrade function:

```
public async Task<long> DeleteGradeAsync(long studentId, long gradeId)
{

    Grade grade = await _unitOfWork. GetRepository<Grade>().GetFirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == gradeId);
    grade.IsDeleted = true;
    await addToHistoryGrade(grade, HistoryFlag.DELETE);  //this one works as intented, no fix needed

    await _unitofwork.SaveChangesAsync();

    return gradeId;
}
```

the problem is that the helper function takes too long when there are multiple grades. The execution time is about 10 seconds for 10 grades and I want to optimize it.

I tried deleteing the grades with this Linq, but I couldn't manage to call the logging function for each grade that was deleted:

`var grades = grades.Where(x => x.isDeleted != true).ToList().Select(c => { c.isDeleted = true; return c; });`

How could I design this such that not many calls to the database are made in a foreach loop, which probably slows my application, while also maintaining the logging feature?

Comment: Please don't vandalize questions.

Comment: Ok, will keep in mind, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, i don't know your resopsitory. By the syntax, this is EF core.

So, I think EFCore.BulkExtensions will solve your problem. Or dapper...

https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

Use carefully - BulkExtensions are licensed under the Dual License v1.0 which you must Buy if do not meet criteria for free usage.

```
_unitOfWork.GetRepository<Grade>().Where(x => x.IdStudent == id).BatchDeleteAsync();
```

If u don't want to use external libraries, u can write your own sql script and run it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries

```
_unitOfWork.Database.ExecuteSql($"DELETE FROM {tableName} WHERE IdStudent = {id}");
```

Comment: i also like to read sql requests from EF. `protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)` with `optionsBuilder.LogTo()` and `optionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging()` inside. It often helps to understand why a particular query is running slowly. This can only be used during development.

Comment: And about passing IEnumerable into methods - use it very very carefully. If your IEnumerable is IQueryable, u will read row by row on every iteration. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cLsmW7a8MkU

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But how can I call the function I use for logging, to record every grade that was deleted?

Comment: Again, i don't know your log function. If it's just row in file, i would do one more requst. `var grades = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<Grade>().Where(x => x.IdStudent == id).ToList()` and pass them into your log function. Or use events https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/events (never used it before. seems interesting and useful). If log is row in DB, i would use triggers.